# Share button- hover & Googleplus/Facebook links

Tags: html, css

I've created content that  will show an image, and when you hover over it, then the background image shows over top of it. It works great, but I am trying to turn this functionality into a link. This means when I hover over the image, it then becomes a link. In this case the link is actually Googleplus share string.

http://jsfiddle.net/54Lr28ro/

When I got the Google HTML link to show over top of my image, I've tryed "text-indent: -9999px; with no luck in making the link text only to disappear. The link just disappears off the page completely.

```
<span class="social-googleplus">
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank" >Google+</a><img src="http://mydiscountman.com/mdm-content/themes/clipper/images/googleplus-black64x64.png" width="64" height="64" title alt="social-googleplus-button-color">
</span>
```

CSS:

```
span.social-googleplus {background-image:url("http://mydiscountman.com/mdm-content/themes/clipper/images/googleplus-color64x64.png");
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    height:64px;
    width:64px;
    left: 332px;
    top: 80px;

}
span.social-googleplus:hover img {visibility:hidden;}
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of giving styles to `img` use this add styles for `<a>` use `background-image` and on `hover` change `background-image`

it will act as the link

```css
    #googleplus {
        background:url(http://mydiscountman.com/mdm-content/themes/clipper/images/googleplus-black64x64.png);
        display:block;
        position: absolute;
        height:64px;
        width:64px;
        left: 332px;
        top: 80px;
    }
    span:hover #googleplus {
        background-image:url("http://mydiscountman.com/mdm-content/themes/clipper/images/googleplus-color64x64.png");
    }
```

```html
<span class="social-googleplus">
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank" id="googleplus">
</a></span>
```